# Recovering unsaved quicktime recording

Tags: macos, data-recovery, quicktime, autosave

I just recorded a quicktime video but I closed my lid before stopping it. Now it isn't saved! Is there a way to recover this very important recording?

This is empty: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information/`

Comment: In every single operating system, from the most complex to the most simple,  the act ***saving your work*** is completely unrelated to it being "user friendly."  If you didn't save it before you stopped the recording and closed the lid - it's gone.  I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: @Allan don't software have an option to autosave things in case of a crash?

Comment: @O'Niel but we aren't the developers of that app.. best hope is to use spotlight or mdfind like tool for video type added in past 24 hours to search the computer. I see you have used https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66114/where-does-quicktime-store-its-screen-recordings?rq=1 this thread for the location said in the question, but documents, movies are worth checking.

Comment: Not necessarily. Killing an app mid process (as you describe) has unintended consequences.  For instance, the app may  never had the chance to write the file.

Comment: @ankii Thanks. Your suggestion to use Spotlight helped me!

Answer (score 2):

I found the file back using Spotlight. Open Finder and press Cmd + F. Than search for filetype 'Movie'.

It was located in `/Users/name/Library/ScreenRecordings`.